# AWS Forecast: Two dataset groups with same dataset ARNs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

I have two dataset groups with two different dataset group ARNs. However, they both have a dataset (the target time series) with the exact same name therefore these datasets have the same ARNs. When I import any data into dataset group 1's dataset using the SDK for python, the same import job will be created for dataset group 2's dataset.

My question is: If I delete the dataset ARN for dataset group 1, will the target dataset and its import jobs for dataset group 2 be deleted as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not delete the dataset ARN to see whether the import jobs for dataset group 2 would be deleted too, however I resolved my issue of having duplicate dataset ARNs by using boto 3 to create a new dataset with a new name and updating the dataset group 2's dataset with the new dataset.